# Give a background a alpha in IE

Tags: html, css

ok, i have this code:

```
<div style="border:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);background:#FF0000">yyyyy</div>
```

but it won't work in IE because it doesn't support rgba(), so, how do i achieve the same effect? hopefully without images or more divs...

Comment: I think this question belongs to doctype.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides IE, there're a few other browsers that do not support rgba. For IE fallback, check this out: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a background image (and applying a pngfix for IE6), you can't. More info: http://www.css3.info/opacity_rgba_and_compromise/